# How to get "&" in urlParams.get in Javascrpt

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm trying to get the parameter used in URL with java script.

example URL:

```
`http://localhost:8002/all-products?categories=Events%20&%20Festivals`
```

I use this code to get the value in categories.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const category_name = urlParams.get("categories")`
```

I only get Events as an output i need to get Events & Festivals but i cant seems to get it

Comment: Because of `&` in the middle, `Festivals` is considered as another key. You need to encode `&`. How are your creating the `URL`?

Comment: im creating the URL based on the item category that the user clicks

Comment: is there another way to get the URL Parameters aside from URLSearchParams ?

Comment: The URL is malformed as of now. You can use `encodeURIComponent("Events & Festivals")` to create the encoded string. Or Use the `URLSearchParams` constructor create an object and use `URLSearchParams.append("categories", "Events & Festivals")` to get the query string.

Comment: that solve the problem thanks ```const new_params = queryString + "&categories=" + encodeURIComponent(this.text.trim())```

Comment: i just need to add encodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 0):

you can add some other character instead of &
for eg. '-'

```
`http://localhost:8002/all-products?categories=Events-Festivals`
```

OR

you can encrypt the category value and pass it in URL

Comment: You can encode any character using `encodeURIComponent` including `&`. There is no need to use `-`